# PC refuses to boot from any hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I turned my pc on, waited for POST to finish, and then was met with the following dialogue: *Reboot and select proper Boot device or insert Boot media in selected Boot device and press a key*

The computer was used last two days ago, and was functioning properly. I double-checked the bios settings to make sure the pc was set to boot from the proper drive. I tested the hard drive to verify functionality, and was able to boot from it using a different pc. I put a known-good drive in and received the same dialogue. I've swapped SATA cables, swapped SATA ports, and still nothing.

Are there any other troubleshooting steps I can try? What might be happening here?

Comment: Could be a dead SATA controller. Can you boot from USB devices (e.g., the same HDD in a USB enclosure)? If so, it's pretty likely to be related to the SATA controller. This wouldn't happen to be a Sandy Bridge chipset (Z67 or H67) would it?

Comment: I'm certain it's the SATA controller because I was able to boot from USB just fine. And no, it is not.

Comment: I'd recommend you try [resetting BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS) and see if that would help you detect the SATA devices properly. Make sure re-configure any manual changes in the BIOS interface after the reset, though. If that doesn't help, I'd advise you to go to the mobo manufacturer's official website and find your model there. Make sure you got the latest BIOS version installed and see if there are any SATA controller/Chipset driver updates available as well. Hope it helps you. Keep us posted.